# std::atomic<std::string>: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEEFEEE in Visual Studio 2013 (VC12) - does not occur when using std::atomic<int>

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

The following minimal code example compiled in Debug mode for x64 and run in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger yields an

> Unhandled exception at ...: Access violation writing location
>   0xFEEEFEEE.

When debugging I see that the access violation occurs at the "return 0;" statement.

(When run from the console without debugger, the error reads "Instruction at 0x... referenced memory at 0xddddddd... The memory could not be written.").

```
#include <atomic>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::atomic<std::string> a1("127.0.0.1:41001");
  std::string ep1_1 = a1.load();
  std::string ep1_2 = a1.load();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::atomic<std::string>` is not legal in standard C++, because `std::string` is not trivially copyable.  Unfortunately there is no requirement for a compiler to refuse this code, but there is also no requirement (and no likelihood) that it will work properly either.

See also: [Does std::atomic<std::string> work appropriately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16876410/4323)