# Is std::atomic<std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>>> valid/safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [Does std::atomic<std::string> work appropriately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876410/does-stdatomicstdstring-work-appropriately), `std::atomic<std::string>` is not valid and may lead to undefined behaviour.

What about `std::atomic<std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>>>`?

`std::optional` has the `operator=` but `std::chrono::time_point` does not, so I'm confued. How do I know for sure for any type?

Comment: AFAIK `std::optional` is trivially copyable only when type it is holding is trivially copyable and `time_point` is trivially copyable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple to check:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<
    std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>>>);
```

Before gcc 8.1 (and the associated libstdc++) the assert fails so it's not safe to use. After gcc 8.1 the assert passes so it's safe.

Before clang 7 (and the asosciated libc++) the assert fails so it's not safe to use. After clang 7 the assert passes and it's safe.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the linked thread, `std::atomic<T>` requires `T` to be trivially copyable.

Here `T` is `std::optional<U>` for some `U`. The `std::optional` class template forwards triviality: its copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, and destructor are each trivial if the same is trivial for `U`.

There is no ironclad guarantee that `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>` is trivially copyable. The underlying representation of the `time_point` may be an arithmetic type or "a class emulating an arithmetic type" ([time.duration]/2), which I read as being sufficiently flexible to permit *e.g.* nontrivial copy constructors (even if they have the same semantics as a trivial copy constructor).  If that's the case, the `time_point` will not be trivially copyable.

In any case, `std::atomic<std::optional<std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>>>` is safe to use *if it compiles*. The compiler must issue a diagnostic if the `T` in `std::atomic<T>` is not trivially copyable, since the standard says "The program is ill-formed" if this condition is not met ([atomics.types.generic]/1). In previous versions of the standard, the wording was "... shall be trivially copyable", which is also a diagnosable rule since it doesn't say "otherwise the behavior is undefined" or anything similar.